# Which content types are available to the data folder object?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, webservices

Looking at http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/datafolder/

How can I find out what values are available to the ContentType property? I know of "email", and "content", merely by guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Workbench is not available for Marketing Cloud. A list of available content types for data folders can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/datafolder.htm).

Unfortunately it seem's, that not every listed ContentType is valid e.g when you try to create a automation folder using ContentType "automations" you will receive an error .... not a valid Folder ContentType

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to find this would be via the workbench.

To access the workbench, go to this URL: https://workbench.developerforce.com and login with your SF credentials.

Then click on the menu: Info > Metadata Types & Components

I think you might find the information you are looking for there.